# pivot in group by ranges and count number elements in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R language. can Anyone provide some example on 
How Can I summarize two columns namely age and number of students into rows and columns of ranges which gives count of number of students each across each range.

[image]

expected pivot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the use of [`cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html) and some tabulating functions. First, some sample data (in the future, please provide some data in your question, and *usable* data, not an image of it, since I generally do not want to transcribe numbers if I can avoid it).

```
set.seed(2)
n <- 100
x <- data.frame(age = sample(4:8, size=n, replace=TRUE),
                size = sample(3:14, size=n, replace=TRUE))
head(x,n=10)
#    age size
# 1    4    5
# 2    7    8
# 3    6   14
# 4    4   12
# 5    8    6
# 6    8   10
# 7    4   13
# 8    8    8
# 9    6    4
# 10   6    4
```

Now the use of `cut`, which divides values based on assigned "breaks":

```
agebins <- c(3,5,7,9)
sizebins <- c(3,6,9,12,15)
cut(head(x$age), agebins)
# [1] (3,5] (5,7] (5,7] (3,5] (7,9] (7,9]
# Levels: (3,5] (5,7] (7,9]
cut(head(x$size), sizebins)
# [1] (3,6]   (6,9]   (12,15] (9,12]  (3,6]   (9,12] 
# Levels: (3,6] (6,9] (9,12] (12,15]
```

By default, it generates `factor`s, though you could opt (if you didn't need the visual of `(5,7]` indicating "greater than 5, less than or equal to 7").

Ok, let's capture those bins into the data.frame and tabulate it.

```
x$agebin <- cut(x$age, agebins, right = FALSE)
x$sizebin <- cut(x$size, sizebins, right=FALSE)
head(x)
#   age size agebin sizebin
# 1   4    5  [3,5)   [3,6)
# 2   7    8  [7,9)   [6,9)
# 3   6   14  [5,7) [12,15)
# 4   4   12  [3,5) [12,15)
# 5   8    6  [7,9)   [6,9)
# 6   8   10  [7,9)  [9,12)
```

There are two base functions that tabulate well, `table` and `xtabs`:

```
table(x$agebin, x$sizebin)
#        
#         [3,6) [6,9) [9,12) [12,15)
#   [3,5)     6     7      5       6
#   [5,7)    13     7      6      12
#   [7,9)    11    10      7      10
with(x, table(agebin, sizebin))
#        sizebin
# agebin  [3,6) [6,9) [9,12) [12,15)
#   [3,5)     6     7      5       6
#   [5,7)    13     7      6      12
#   [7,9)    11    10      7      10
```

I used the `with(x, ...)` notation, and this preserves the axis names. I prefer the second function, though:

```
xtabs(~ agebin + sizebin, data=x)
#        sizebin
# agebin  [3,6) [6,9) [9,12) [12,15)
#   [3,5)     6     7      5       6
#   [5,7)    13     7      6      12
#   [7,9)    11    10      7      10
```

If you want marginal sums, that's not hard either:

```
xtb <- xtabs(~ agebin + sizebin, data=x)
xtb <- cbind(xtb, RowTotal = rowSums(xtb))
xtb <- rbind(xtb, ColTotal = colSums(xtb))
xtb
#          [3,6) [6,9) [9,12) [12,15) RowTotal
# [3,5)        6     7      5       6       24
# [5,7)       13     7      6      12       38
# [7,9)       11    10      7      10       38
# ColTotal    30    24     18      28      100
```

Comment: Sorry about the sample  data. it took like one hour for me to understand this. I think you provided a lovely example. Thank you.Just one question Can this be applied to float kind of data?

Comment: All you have to do to find out is try: `cut(pi, c(1,3,5,7))`. (Yes, it does work with floats.)

Comment: Yeah. It does work with floats. I think your example speeded up my learning curve for R. Thank you immensely.